# Unable to call a method inside RSpec Shared Example

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Trying to use RSpec shared example to test invalid authorization header.

Below is the code

```
describe 'PUT#update' do
let(:account) do
  account = build(:account)
  account.save!
  account
end

def jwt_token(timestamp)
  payload = { account_id: account.id, timestamp: timestamp }
  JWT.encode(payload, ALERT_MGMT_CONFIG['app_secret'])
end

shared_examples 'invalid_header' do |header|
  it "with header '#{header}' responds Unauthorized" do
    request.headers['Authorization'] = header
    attributes = { name: 'TestAccountChanged', full_domain: 'FullDomainChanged' }
    put :update, params: { id: account.id, account: attributes }
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(response.status).to eq(401)
  end
end


describe 'Authentication failure' do
  include_examples 'invalid_header', 'nil'
  include_examples 'invalid_header', 'LoremIpsum'
  include_examples 'invalid_header', 'TOKEN LoremIpsum'
  include_examples 'invalid_header',  "TOKEN #{jwt_token(Time.now.utc + 5.days)}"
end
end
```

I am trying to access jwt_token method and am getting this error.

```
 Failure/Error: include_examples 'invalid_header',  "TOKEN #{jwt_token(Time.now.utc + 5.days)}"`jwt_token` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
```

How do i resolve this? How do i make it available on example group?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `shared_example` inside your spec file, `shared_example` are really useful when you want implement the same behaviour between different spec file.

I fully recommend it to not use `shared_example` in your present case but use a simple `def method` as follow:

```
def authentication_fail header
  request.headers['Authorization'] = header
  attributes = { name: 'TestAccountChanged', full_domain: 'FullDomainChanged' }
  put :update, params: { id: account.id, account: attributes }
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(response.status).to eq(401)
end
```

and then

```
describe 'Authentication failure' do
  authentication_fail(nil)
  authentication_fail('LoremIpsum')
  authentication_fail('TOKEN LoremIpsum')
  authentication_fail( "TOKEN #{jwt_token(Time.now.utc + 5.days)}")
end
```

I hope it could help.